# Changing background images in Wordpress theme

Tags: php, css, image, wordpress, background

I am using a Wordpress theme and want to make it change the background images automatically. So, I used some PHP code and tried to build it into the website, but something is not working and I cannot figure it out, as I am not very good with PHP.

functions.php:

```
<?php
$bilder = glob( "images/*.jpg" );
shuffle( $bilder );
$zufall = imagecreatefromjpeg($bilder[0]);
imagejpeg($zufall); 
?>
```

... and simply in CSS of my Wordpress:

```
body { 
background: url('<?php print $zufall ?>') no-repeat center center fixed;
}
```

But for some reason it just does not show the pictures and I am really off with my wisdom now. :(

Can you help me or tell me the error?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This should work - you just need the filename of the image which is in the $bilder array

functions.php:

```
<?php
$bilder = glob( "images/*.jpg" );
shuffle( $bilder );
$zufall = $bilder[0];
?>
```

CSS:

```
body { 
background: url('image/<?php print $zufall ?>') no-repeat center center fixed;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not help. I am getting a feeling that the functions.php in the Wordpress theme is the wrong file to put the PHP code, but I just do not know anything about Wordpress or where to put custom PHP stuff. I can state the website, where I have the problem right now, if that helps.

Comment: I just checked back. Obviously, the functions.php file is the correct file to put custom PHP code. :) So, it is not that. :\